# Python Index Error (unexpected) List append function

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, append

Can someone tell me why this code is giving me an indexing error?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
    new = []    
    for i in range(0, (len(nums)-1)):
        if nums[i] != nums[(i+1)]:
            new.append(nums[i])
    new.append(nums[-1]) #this is what causes the index error
    return new
```

Comment: This will only happen in one case: `nums = []` (or `()` or `""` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

This will fail if u pass empty sequence to @remove_adjacent. like remove_adjacent([])

look at this i just rewrite it.

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
    new = []    
    for i in range(0, len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i] != nums[(i+1)]:
            new.append(nums[i])
    if len(nums):new.append(nums[-1]) # it works
    return new
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as jonrsharpe said, you `remove_adjacent` function miss to handle one condition: `nums` is an empty `list` or `tuple` or some array type support random access by index.

You have to deal with the last element(`nums[-1]`) especially because there is no element after the last element to compare with in you algorithm.

I think maybe this is a cleaner way to implement the `remove_adjacent` function:

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
    new = []    
    for i in nums:
        if not new or new[-1] != i:
            new.append(i)
    return new
```

In this way, you do not need to deal with the last element especially.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the problem completely and also make it work with any iterable and not just sequences you could use `itertools.groupby()`:

```
from itertools import groupby


def remove_adjacent(items):
    return [item for item, _ in groupby(items)]
```